# How to compile 32-bit programs with Intel Fortran? `ifortvars.bat ia32 VS2015` fails

Tags: windows, fortran, intel-fortran

I've been working on making Fortran 32bit-application on Intel Fortran compiler, which I got as a part of Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Windows(evaluation edition).
Before installing it, Visual Studio 2015 Community had been already installed.

As a setup beforehand, I execute command below:

```
ifortvars.bat ia32 VS2015
```

then when I try ifort command, it fails, which issues error like `there's no command 'ifort'`.

If I command like this as a setup, it succeeds:

```
ifortvars.bat intel64 VS2015
```

Is there any way to execute ifort command to make Fortran 32bit-application?

Comment: Please show the exact steps you are executing and the **exact** error messages. Not *"error like"* but an exact copy and paste. Please see [ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: you are attempting to use the 32 bit compiler. with ifort you should be able to create (compile and link) 32 executables while using the 64 bit compiler. Why do you want to make 32bit executable?

Comment: But the command itself is correct. Does the compiler version you have really contain the 32-bit compiler? Note that there is also the official support forum https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows and you are likely to get good support there.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Perhaps the `-m32` option is the answer to this question, although it does not treat that error message.

Comment: I'll show exact steps:  
1.Installed Visual Studio 2015 Community.  
2.Installed Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 Cluster edition for Windows.  
3.Executed command:`ifortvars.bat ia32 vs2015`.  
4.Executed command:`ifort.exe /dll test.f90`  
5.Got an error:"'ifort.exe' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。 ", which means "'ifort.exe' is not recognized as an internal/external command nor an executable program nor bat file'".  
  
In step4 I want to create dll, which is due to be used from the other application.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl As in step5 above, I'm not able to use ifort command when I execute `ifortvars.bat ia32 vs2015`.

@VladimirF Sorry, it seems there is no 32bit-compiler in my computer.
When installing Intel Parallel Studio, I was not able to select an option for fortran 32bit-compiler because it was grayed out. I'm not sure why it was not allowed to select it.

Comment: I think you don't need it, that's why it was grayed out. And if it is not installed you can't casll it, obviously. Just use the m32 option.

Comment: @VladimirF m32 option didn't work for me, but reinstalling parallel studio enabled to select 32bit-compiler, making executing command `ifortvars.bat ia32 vs2015` available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try the compiler option `/Qm32` (actually already mentioned by @vladimir and @Pierre de Buyl yesterday).

You might check if the executable exists: `C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017\windows\bin\ia32\ifort.exe`. If not, you should probably reinstall.

Even better, instead of calling `ifortvars.bat`, open the Intel command prompt from the Windows menu: `Start > Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 > Compiler 17.0 Update 2 for IA-32 Visual Studio 2015 environment`. This will properly setup the PATH/environment.

FWIW, I've never used `ifortvars.bat`. Instead, I pin the Intel command prompt to the taskbar.

Comment: /Qm32 command didn't help me, and as you mention, I don't have the executable in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017\windows\bin\ia32\`.
But reinstalling Parallel Studio made it possible to select 32bit-compiler when choosing which options to install, enabling me to call `ifortvars.bat` with a `ia32`option. Thank you very much.